# Jquery ajax invalid label

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I making ajax call to the follwoing URL

http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v1/drugname/sanctura%20xr/spls.json

I keep on  getting invalid label error in firebug console. Here's my ajax code. Please let me know where am I going wrong.

```
//Make an ajax call
            $.ajax({ 
                type:'GET',
                dataType:'jsonp',
                 url: 'http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v1/drugname/sanctura/spls.json',
                 //crossDomain: true,

                 beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
                  },


                 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                     console.log('status '+xhr.status);
                     console.log(''+xhr.responseText);
                     console.log(''+ajaxOptions);
                     console.log(''+thrownError);

                 },
                 success: function(){     
                    alert('success');
                 }
             });
```

Comment: To use jsonp the server needs to be set up to add the callback as a wrapper around the response data. Many jsonp enabled servers expect a parameter "callback" (set by default by jquery) to be the name of a javascript function on the page that will be called when the data responds. For example `http://foo.com/data/data.json?callbcack=bar`  will send back the data like so `bar(/*data goes here/*)` - Anyway, it doesn't look like the server is responding with a callback wrapped around the data. If your page has secure access to that domain, a regular ajax call will do. Otherwise, you need a proxy.

Comment: Or in simpler terms: your URL returns JSON, but your code tries to treat it as JSONP (which doesn't work).

Comment: When do a regular json I get the follwoing error. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v1/drugname/sanctura/spls.json. Origin http://localhost:9011 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Yes, standard Ajax requests can't go to a different domain. JSONP doesn't do an Ajax request at all (though jQuery wraps it up in its Ajax methods), it basically requests a script, which is why it does work with a different domain, but it only works if the site you are sending the request to is set up to allow it - which your example site isn't. You can work around this by making a standard Ajax request to your own web server, and then your server-side code would make the request to the URL you've specified and return the result back to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

nnnnnn's suggestion for building your own proxy to the API is a good suggestion of getting around these things.

I just wanted to add for people ending up here in the future that DailyMed Web Service's now has the proper CORS header. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to "*", which means anyone can access the API's through AJAX.

You can now user regular AJAX with DailyMed Web Services.